# Padding-top showing when height on div is set to 0%

Tags: css

I have a nav that is positioned at the bottom with the following CSS:

```
#myFirstNav {
display: flex;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
justify-content: space-around;
padding: 10px;
background-color: black;
}
```

I then have an overlay menu that pops up, when you click on one on the links in #myFirstNav. It has the following CSS:

```
.overlay {
height: 0;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
background-color: white;
transition: 0.5s;
border: 2px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
border-bottom: 0;
}
```

What troubles me is that the 2px border on the .overlay is showing up on the #myFirstNav background. Is there anyway to shift the .overlay div 2px down, so that the border doesn't show up on the #myFirstNav background?

[image: The padding showing at the bottom]

Comment: This is a bit difficult to visualize.  Is it possible to include a screenshot, or create a working snippet that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @AlexanderNied Added a picture where the border is showing at the bottom. It is the gray line.

Comment: Giving `bottom: -2px;` to overlay and `height:100%;` wont solve your problem? If you provide a fiddle i can help you more. Regards

Comment: There are a number of things that could potentially be causing this, but there is no way to tell for sure without you also sharing the markup on your page as well.

Comment: @ColinCline I tried that early today, and it gave me some really weird result. But now it works, sometimes the hard things has the simplest answers :)

Comment: @user3403590 Indeed. Have a nice day/night.